Is there a treatment of Lie Algebra Modules in the Literature that are Lie Algebras by themselves?
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be an arbitrary Lie algebra. Then we define
$$
\mathfrak{A(g)} = \left\{ \alpha \in \mathfrak{gl(g)} \; :\;  [\alpha(X),Y]+[X,\alpha(Y)]=0  \,\forall\,  X,Y \in \mathfrak{g} \right\}
$$
which I call antisymmetric transformations. The name was given by deGroote who investigated them (together with symmetric and isometric transformations) as invariants on algorithmic varieties of general multiplications - not only Lie multiplications - hoping to improve the computational asymptotic bound of matrix multiplication via algebraic means. While I am not aware that this approach actually resulted in better estimations for the matrix multiplication, it reveals some interesting properties in case the multiplication is a Lie algebra multiplication.
First of all, $\mathfrak{A(g)}$ is again a Lie algebra and via
$$
X.\alpha =[\operatorname{ad}X,\alpha]
$$
also a $\mathfrak{g}$-module. It produces a couple of nice formulas for instance
$$
[\alpha(X),[Y,Z]]+[\alpha(Y),[Z,X]]+[\alpha(Z),[X,Y]]=0.
$$
Obviously, $\mathfrak{A(g)}=\mathfrak{gl(g)}$ in case $\mathfrak{g}$ is abelian. A straightforward calculation along the root systems give $\mathfrak{A(g)}=0$ in case $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple. Any Lie algebra with a one-dimensional ideal $\mathfrak{I}=\bigl\langle R\,|\, [X,R]=\lambda(X)R\bigr\rangle $ allows a antisymmetric transformation $\alpha(X)=\lambda(X)R.$ Another class of Lie algberas with non-trivial antisymmetric Lie algebras are what I call one-liners ($n>2$):
$$
\mathfrak{g}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\ast&\ast&\ldots&\ast \\ 0&0&\ldots&0 \\ \vdots &\vdots&\cdots&\vdots \\ 0&0&\ldots&0\end{pmatrix}\right\}\cong \mathfrak{A(g)}
$$
and
$$
\mathfrak{A(B)}=\mathfrak{sl}(2)
$$
for the two-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{B}.$ Hence, if we particularly consider solvable Lie algebras, then we can observe:
The more complicated the Lie multiplication the smaller are Lie algebras of the antisymmetric transformations and vice versa.
My idea was to use this framework for the investigation of particularly solvable Lie algebras. The operation opens the framework to the world of Cartan-Eilenberg complexes and homology theory. Unfortunately, even figuring out whether $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ can occur for other Lie algebras as antisymmetric transformation Lie algebra turns out to be a forest of cases.
So that's my question: Are there known theories that could help me here, e.g. about Lie algebra representations on other Lie algebras, and specifically modules which are themselves Lie algebras of solvable Lie algebras beyond Lie's theorem?

What you call $\mathfrak{A(g)} $ has been studied more generally by Leger and Luks by the name of generalised derivations. The spaces are $C(a,b,c)={D\in End(\mathfrak{g}) \mid aD([x,y])=b[D(x),y]+c[x,D(y)]$. Your space is $C(0,1,1)$. See the paper here.

Thank you. The special case $C(0,1,1),$ i.e. a case where the resulting space is automatically again a Lie algebra, allows towers of Lie algebras with a kind of "oscillating" multiplication complexity. I thought it would be a nice idea to enter the world of solvable (centerless) Lie algebras.

The spaces $C(a,b,c)$, and their dimensions are interesting invariants, also for solvable Lie algebras.

I will read the paper.
